# Convert Dynamic to Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

The following code is a modification of Wolfram code I found under ClickPane Help. I want to convert from Dynamic to Manipulate to make it easier for me to add various controls. I do want to keep the ClickPane formulation. Thanks.

```
DynamicModule[{f = {}}, 
 ClickPane[
  Dynamic@Plot[f, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> 5, Frame -> True],
(AppendTo[f, Exp[-(t - #[[1]])]*#[[2]]]) &]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
  ClickPane[Plot[g, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> x, Frame -> True], 
    (AppendTo[g, Exp[-(t - #[[1]])]*#[[2]]]) &], 
  {x, 1, 10}, Initialization :> {g = {}}]
```